# Does int vs long comparison hurt performance in Java?

Tags: java, comparison, int, long-integer

Does comparing an int and long hurt performance? i.e.

```
int x = 1;
long y = 2;
if (x < y) doStuff();
```

as opposed to:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
if (x < y) ...
```

Is there a conversion of types? or does the layout of bits in memory allow a straight comparison? (i.e. the extra bits in the long can all assumed to be 0 for an int)

Comment: Does it hurt performance, compared to what?

Comment: as opposed to int vs int comparison

Comment: It's an Widening Primitive Conversion (See: JLS chapter 5). That said, this has a distinct premature optimization smell; in the real world it makes no difference.

Comment: Yes, I am mostly curious, it is not a performance issue

Comment: Running various tests on Java 15 long is ~7.5x faster than int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JLS is a good reference, and makes the requirement for type promotion clear, but no one has talked about the essential question.

At the machine level (post JIT compilation or down deep in the JVM), a processor with a 64-bit ALU will be likely to do the 64- to 32-bit comparison with one instruction to sign-extend the 32-bit operand and a second to do the 64-bit wide comparison followed by a branch around the `doStuff` call.

For the `int` to `int` 32-bit comparison, the sign extension can be omitted.  So the difference is one instruction or one cycle for modern cores.

If the machine has a 32-bit ALU, then the 64-bit comparison probably requires 4 instructions: compare, branch, test, branch.  But it might be done in 3 (sub with borrow, sub, branch) with the right instructions and/or an extra register.

The `int` to `int` requires two: compare and branch.  So the difference is 1 or 2 instructions/cycles.

There are very few programs where 1 or 2 cycles make a meaningful performance difference. Use the type you need to ensure your program will work under all contingencies you can imagine over the next decade or so.  Forget the couple of cycles.

NB Where 64-bits actually cause a meaningful performance hit is inflating data structure (and to a lesser extent code) sizes by a factor of 2 so that cache and page misses become more frequent.  But again you should not worry about this in advance.

Unfortunately Java makes it impossible to alias the unboxed types.  A change from `int` to `long` or `float` to `double` and back is non-trivial: a serious language flaw in many situations.

Answer (score 18):

The Java Language Specification says that **binary numeric promotion** occurs and the `int` therefore is converted to a `long`. In practice the conversion is really trivial - it's not an expensive operation on most modern hardware. However, this whole issue shouldn't really be a performance concern; you use a long not because of performance, but because you need to be able to manage larger numeric values.

And as always with performance questions, the real answer is that:

a) you shouldn't worry about performance until it becomes an issue

b) at that stage you should profile or conduct measurements to see what the effect is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), section 5.6.2, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of the numerical comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. This means that `int` will be promoted to `long` before the comparison.

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion
>      (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
>
> After the type conversion, if any, value set conversion (§5.1.13) is applied to each operand. Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, / and % (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and - (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)

Comment: I think this is relevant, but not the whole story, since we need to know how the JRE represents int and long internally, which will affect how the it performs the conversion.

Comment: @nhahtdh - it is safe to assume that the JVM (not the JRE!) represents `int` and `long` using native signed 32-bit and 64-bit integer representation, and uses native instructions to do 32 to 64 bit conversion, and `long` arithmetic and comparisons.

Comment: @nhahtdh The entire question is basically irrelevant; You might save a few nanoseconds over millions of widening operations. And since it would be *implementation dependent* the answer is that if the OP really wants to know the performance difference, they should measure it on their JVM + hardware. The JLS simply states what is required by the JVM.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I am totally aware that knowing the answer to this question doesn't save you time, since there are tons of other things that overwhelms any time you can save from it.

Comment: +1 for the @BrianRoach's comment ... though *"a few nanoseconds over millions of widening operations"* is probably overstating the case ... a bit.  You might save a few milliseconds over MILLIONS of widening operations.  But your basic point is 100% correct.  This is *most likely* irrelevant.

Comment: Fair enough. How about a gaggle? (Not to be confused with a google)

Comment: @StephenC: I am a bit confused between JRE and JVM, but my point still stands. It is safe to assume so since the JVM has to follow the specs, but the size of `int` and `long` used internally in JVM doesn't have to be 32-bit and 64-bit (unless other part of the specs specifies that JVM has to do so internally, which is quite unlikely since the specs should allow for the JVM to be implemented on different hardware). If anything, those width may be chosen for ease of implementation on certain architecture.

Comment: @nhahtdh - And my point remains - for most real implementations of Java, the hardware ISA *does* have native 64-bit arithmetic instructions, and those instructions *will* be used.